# Changing chapter title font

Tags: fonts, titles

I´m struggeling changing the font of my chapter, section etc. titles. Seems that it should be pretty easy with `\documentclass{scrreprt}` but I´m not successfull anyway. I´m using Latin Modern for the text. I want the headings in Iwona (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/iwona/)

Here´s my MWE and thank you very much.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\iwona}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command \iwona is not existing

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\usefont{T1}{iwona}{m}{n}\selectfont\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```